# ref.updateChildValues triggers .childMoved twice firebase realtime database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this method which takes these dict and saves as an update to the database but it triggers the .childMoved twice which is listening to user chat

```
let message = ["message":message,
               "uid":my_uid,
               "timestamp":Firebase.ServerValue.timestamp()] as [String : Any]

let myChatID_info = ["timestamp":Firebase.ServerValue.timestamp(),
                     "uid": user_uid,
                     "unread_messages":0] as [String : Any]

let user_chatID_info = ["timestamp":Firebase.ServerValue.timestamp(),
                        "uid":my_uid,
                        "unread_messages":unread_messages+1] as [String : Any]

let childUpdates = ["/user_chats/\(my_uid)/\(chat_key)/":myChatID_info,
                    "/user_chats/\(user_uid)/\(chat_key)/":user_chatID_info,
                    "messages/\(chat_key)/\(message_key)/":message]

self.ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

This is the method that listens to the user chat 
where user_chats is

```
user_chats = ref.child(chatConstants.user_chats).child(myUsername)

func addChatMovedListener(){
    user_chats.queryOrdered(byChild: chatConstants.timestamp).observe(.childMoved, with: {(snapshot) in
        print("chatMoved")
        let index = self.indexOfChat(key: snapshot.key)
        self.getChatObject(snapshot: snapshot) { chat in
            if(index == -1){
                self.chats.insert(chat, at: 0)
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
            } else {
                self.chats[index] = chat
                let chat = self.chats.remove(at: index)
                self.chats.insert(chat, at: 0)
                self.tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you updating two child nodes causing a re-ordering?

Comment: yes the timestamp would be updated which will cause it to reorder since it observed based on timestamp

Comment: Also I just noticed that when its updated the .childAdded is also triggered but only the first time, every time its updated after that .childAdded is not triggered. I will edit my question soon.

Comment: Oh also only one child node is updated not two. its listening on user_chats/uid which is updated

Comment: If .childAdded is firing that means you are adding data, not modifying existing data. And if you are adding data, that could cause the ordering to change as well. That's what I would start looking at.